# How do I force a picture to be placed on a page, disregarding margins?

Tags: floats, margins, diagrams

I have a picture that I would like to place on the frontpage of a student paper that I am working on, and it is being pushed on to the next page by LaTeX. I want it to be placed in a specific place, which will cause it to cross left, bottom and right margin for text. Is there any way of placing the image independently of the margins?

Heres an example that looks like what I'm doing

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (0pt,0.3\textheight) -- (0pt,-\textheight) -- (\textwidth,-\textheight) -- (\textwidth,0.3\textheight) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
{
\hspace{110pt}
\fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont Title
    }

\begin{figure}[h!]
\vspace*{-50pt}
\hspace*{-15pt}
\includegraphics[width=387pt]{imagename}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Edit: I don't know if the image width here works with this simpler example, but it's what I want in the original document.

Comment: Is the picture the only thing on the page?

Comment: Floating figure environment?

Comment: @egreg: No, there is also some text, and a tikz drawing for framing.

I am not familiar with Floating figure environment. Will look into it though!

Comment: Can you add a schematic example of what you have?

Comment: @Deltat Please, click on edit below your question and add the code there. After adding the text, select it and click on the `{}` button above the typing box.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your TikZ "picture" is meant to draw a rectangle around the lower 70% of the text block. If so, be sure to add `\noindent` before drawing the rectangle.

Since I don't have access to the file `imagename.pdf`, I've modified the code below to draw a generic black rectangle of width `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics} % just for this example
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent % need to add this instruction
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (0pt,0.3\textheight) -- (0pt,-\textheight) -- (\textwidth,-\textheight) -- (\textwidth,0.3\textheight) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
{
\hspace{110pt}
\fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont Title
}


\begin{figure}[h!]
%\vspace*{-50pt}
%\hspace*{-15pt}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imagename}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My main issue is that the image becomes too long, and therefore jumps into the next page. Is there any way of preventing this?

Comment: @Deltat - not knowing how big the image is in real life, I'm afraid I can't give firm advice. You could try `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.45\textheight, keepaspectratio]{imagename}`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works. Since tikz can draw a picture outside of the margins for me already, that's what I'm using it for anyways, I used it to draw the picture I wanted as well. I altered the lines in my code to be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (mypicture) at (194pt,-330pt) {\includegraphics[width=387pt]{picture}};
\draw (0pt,0.3\textheight) -- (0pt,-\textheight) -- (\textwidth,-\textheight) -- (\textwidth,0.3\textheight) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The coordinates and width of the picture are just the ones that worked in my original document. Probably won't work in this example version.